# asp.net one of a kind Secured Page problem

Tags: asp.net

If I use the following setting, I am unable to use Server.Transfer()/Response.Redirect() to redirect to a secured page:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
        <forms
          name="CookieDemo"
          loginUrl="Default.aspx"
          protection="All"
          timeout="30"
          path="/"
        />
      </authentication>
      <authorization>
        <deny
          users="?"
        />
```

I need to protect all pages except Default.aspx.

What should I do to solve this problem?

Note that, I am not using asp.net's built-in membership provider.

Here is my redirecting code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            AspNetUtil util = new AspNetUtil(this);

            //util.DisposeCookie("user");

            UserTypeEnum userType = EnumUtility.ConvertToEnum(util.GetCookieValue("user", "usertype"));
            string username = util.GetCookieValue("user", "username");

            if (userType == UserTypeEnum.Student)
            {
                //Server.Transfer("~/Student/StudentControlPanel.aspx?username=" + username);
                Response.Redirect("~/Student/StudentControlPanel.aspx?username=" + username);
            }
            else if (userType == UserTypeEnum.Teacher)
            {
                //Server.Transfer("~/Teacher/TeacherControlPanel.aspx?username=" + username);
                Response.Redirect("~/Teacher/TeacherControlPanel.aspx?username=" + username);
            }
        }

protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string username = this.usernameTextBox.Text;
            string password = this.passwordTextBox.Text;

            bool success = Ice_Web_Portal.BO.User.LogIn(username, password);

            if (success)
            {
                Ice_Web_Portal.BO.User user = Ice_Web_Portal.BO.User.GetUserByUserName(username);

                Ice_Web_Portal.BO.UserTypeEnum loginUserType = user.UserTypeEnum;

                if (loginUserType == UserTypeEnum.Student)
                {
                    AspNetUtil util = new AspNetUtil(this);
                    util.SaveInCookie("user", "username", username, 3600);
                    util.SaveInCookie("user", "usertype", "Student", 3600);

                    //Server.Transfer("~/Student/StudentControlPanel.aspx?username=" + username);
                    Response.Redirect("~/Student/StudentControlPanel.aspx?username=" + username);
                }
                else if (loginUserType == UserTypeEnum.Teacher)
                {
                    AspNetUtil util = new AspNetUtil(this);
                    util.SaveInCookie("user", "username", username, 3600);
                    util.SaveInCookie("user", "usertype", "Teacher", 3600);

                    //Server.Transfer("~/Teacher/TeacherControlPanel.aspx?username=" + username);                
                    Response.Redirect("~/Teacher/TeacherControlPanel.aspx?username=" + username);
                }
                else
                {
                    labLoginMessage.Text = "Sorry! Type of user couldn't be determined!";
                }
            }
            else
            {
                labLoginMessage.Text = Ice_Web_Portal.BO.User.LoginMessage;
            }
        }
```

This is not working either:

```
<location path="Default.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*"></allow>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASP.NET Forms authentication has its own Cookie that it uses to determine if the user is authenticated. Instead of using Response.Redirect or Server.Transfer, use System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage, which will set the cookie and redirect the user.